# Change OData method key from integer to string

Tags: c#, rest, odata, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having problems switching my OData method to use a string as a key, instead of an integer as a key. It seems to behave as an integer no matter what??

The old method (notice the integer):

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Order> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    IQueryable<Order> result = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

The old url (worked great):

```
api/orders(250)/
```

The new method (notice the string):

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Order> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    IQueryable<Order> result = db.Orders.Where(o => o.MyCustomId == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

The new url *should* ultimately be like:

```
api/orders('13-Abc.56.77.Blah.Blah')/
```

My Web API routing looks like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    //OData configuration
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Order>("orders");
    builder.EntityType<Order>().Function("getordersummary").Returns<OrderSummary>();

    var _model = builder.GetEdmModel();
    var defaultConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config, _model);
    var conventions = defaultConventions.Except(defaultConventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>());

    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "api",
        routingConventions: conventions,
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        model: _model);

    //make uri calls much easier
    config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(true);

    //ensure JSON responses
    var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

The new url does not work for:

```
/api/orders('13-2011.01')/
/api/orders(13-2011.01)/
/api/orders('ABC')/
/api/orders(ABC)/
```

But the new url does work for:

```
/api/orders(13201101)/
/api/orders(123)/
```

If I set a breakpoint on my new "Get" controller method while debugging, it only gets hit when the new url looks like this:

```
/api/orders(13201101)/
```

The breakpoint will not be hit if the new url looks like this:

```
/api/orders('13-2011.01')/
/api/orders(13-2011.01)/
```

In my SQL server database table, I made the primary key [MyCustomId] field. I then updated my EntityFramework model (.edmx) and assigned the Entity key to [MyCustomId] field in my [Order] class. The urls still do not work correctly.

**What is wrong with my routing? 
Why does the new url only accept integers, when clearly it's defined as: "[FromODataUri] string key" ?**

** Update: I already have added the re-write handler for allowing "dots" in my url. I should mention that. That works fine and was working before this migration. For example, we have urls like this working:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApplication/OrderInfo/OrderSummary/13-2011.01/
```

It is simply the OData method that is not working.

Comment: BTW, you don't need (and shouldn't have) those trailing slashes on your URIs. They are harmless (because the OData URI parser is ignoring them), but technically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't changed the key property of the Order entity type in the data model. The convention `ODataConventionModelBuilder` uses to discover the key property of a class `Foo` is to look for a property named `FooId` or `Id` (both case-insensitive). So the key property of your `Order` class is still `OrderId`, which is integer-valued. (If you enable the `MetadataRoutingConvention` and retrieve `/api/$metadata`, you will see this is the case.)

Because the data model says the Order entity type has an integer-valued key, the routing engine is looking for a value with integer syntax in the resource path `/api/orders(key)`. The model-binding engine then happily converts the integer to a string for use as the parameter in your `Get` method.

You can fix the problem in one of two ways:

- Rename `MyCustomId` to `OrderId`, and rename `OrderId` to something else
- Annotate `MyCustomId` with the [`Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute, thereby overriding the naming convention used by `ODataConventionModelBuilder`

Comment: Wow, thank you!! It seems to force me to use the [Key] attribute on the field no matter what, even when I updated my .edmx/EF model to make use of the new primary key. Very strange. I also had alot of trouble with my edmx and updating it. Major pain.